# How to using Asp.net Identity when using Business And DataModel Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm creating application with layered architecture. I have separate
+ 'DataModel' project with only model classes
+ 'BusinessLogic' project that containing my business
+ 'Core' project for run Business from ui
+ 'ViewModel' project
+ 'Web' project with asp.net core application.

My goal was to separate these projects so that Web project knows nothing about DataModel so the Web project should just reference Core and ViewModel. Everything was great until I configured Asp.Net Identity - in order to configure authorization I had to reference DataModel project which I had wanted to avoid. Is it possible to achieve my goal, and (if so) how to do it.

Note:
I'm using this [how to separate model library when using asp.net identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389191/how-to-separate-model-library-when-using-asp-net-identity) for writing my question and i don't find accepted answer as my answer!

Comment: Can you explain more or provide some code? I define my models and business logics in a layer I call Domain Layer which knows nothing about the implementation of it and for User entity I use an interface and in infrastructure layer I implement it with Identity.

Comment: Thanks @Sasan . For now I just create 5  empty project based on my question. but I know that for using Identity in Web project, must add DbContext and using `services.AddIdentity` in Startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a website that uses Identity directly, you must provide it with various Identity "stores": `UserStore<TUser>`, `RoleStore<TRole>`, etc. The default and easiest approach is to use Entity Framework Core as the backing for the store(s), and Identity comes with built-in stores to work with EF Core. However, using that requires access to the context, which means you then will need a dependency on your data layer. There is no way around that when using `AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>`.

If you want to keep your data layer abstracted, then you will need to either 1) use a centralized identity provider, such as IdentityServer or 2) create custom stores.

IdentityServer, for example, supports using both EF and Identity as a backing. That does mean *it* will need a dependency on your data layer, but IdentityServer would be exist in a separate project. Your actual website would handle auth via IdentityServer endpoints, and therefore would have no dependency on your data layer. In fact, it doesn't even know or care that you're using Identity at all at that point.

Creating custom stores will be a bit more difficult, obviously, and unless you provide an true abstraction layer, you'll still ultimately end up with a dependency on your data layer. That might be something like a microservice(s), where the store will actually make HTTP requests to the service to get the objects it needs, instead of making database queries directly. The microservices, then, will hold the data dependency.

One thing you might not be considering in this is that the dependency is there even without a direct reference. For example, if your Core project uses stuff from your DataModel project, and then your Web project uses stuff from your Core project, *your web project has an implicit dependency on your DataModel project*. If you look at the bin folder after building, for example, you're see a DLL for your DataModel project and even one for EF Core there, despite not explictly using either one in your Web project. In this case, using separate projects helps only to division the logic in perhaps a more succinct and understandable way, but it does *not* serve to actually abstract any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I agree with you but are you sure that there is no other way apart from these two ways?